# Are wildcards allowed in the FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains plist when using a custom domain in firebase dynamic links?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

I am setting up dynamic links with custom domains using firebase for unity. In the documentation here, https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive#open-dynamic-links-in-your-app, I can see that I need to add plist entries to the FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains
key to whitelist these domains in my app.

My question is if I can use a wildcard subdomain here, as my setup includes dozens of custom subdomains, some of which may be created after the app has shipped.

```
FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains

  https://*.firebaselinks.example.com/links/
```

Will this work to allow opening the app from any subdomain on firebaselinks.example.com ?

Comment: Hi @Devlin, I'm facing same issue, did you find a way to handle wild card on custom domains ?

Comment: Hi @VictorDias, unforetunately due to a conflict with another library we are using, we did not pursue the deeplinking functionality of firebase dynamic links